# autogen-like script for fresh installed OS

Tags: scripts

I need to make something like my ubuntu build, which can install some basic software and make some folders, what I'm I looking for?

Might be sh script, but there are some chain of apt and other upgrades, so maybe there is more reliable approach

Comment: There are several ways to automatically customize an Ubuntu system. Preseed, Cloud-init, shell scripts, and customized .iso images are all in wide use. None are specifically "autogen-like."